# skipper gridfs image upload

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo, sails-skipper

I'm having a problem in sails js image uploading using skipper gridfs.

My connection is fine but however when I upload an image it logs an error to my terminal

```
 MongoError: error processing query: ns=admin.uploads.chunksTree: $and
    files_id $eq ObjectId('5aa131bc2f0c2cda22b1b8ed')
    n $gte 0
Sort: { files_id: 1, n: 1 }
Proj: {}
 No query solutions
```

I'm using Kitematic.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix? I'm currently having the same issue.

Comment: sorry for my late response, i had the url typed wrong i used '/' instead of '.' to define the collection hope it helps